# Custom Minimize Window Button macOS - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift4, nswindow

I'm developing an app for macOS in Swift. The view I'm designing has the standard "traffic lights" disabled and a transparent full size content title bar. I need to design a new custom traffic light to quit the app and one to minimize the window. I've already found out how to make a custom quit button but I can't manage to create a custom minimize button. I'm new to macOS programming so for sure I'm doing something wrong.

This is the code that I'm trying to use but that does not work:

```
 @IBAction func miniApp(_ sender: Any) {
        NSWindow.miniaturize(self)
    }
```

I'm using Swift 4

I can't figure out the right way to do this. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send that action to current window. If this action is in your view controller then it should be

```
@IBAction func miniApp(_ sender: Any) {
    self.view.window.miniaturize(self)
}
```

Comment: Tried that but nothing happens. Yes the action is in the view controller class

Comment: @Albifer, does you window has [.miniaturizable] style mask?

Comment: I don't know actually. How do I check ?

Comment: @Albifer, would you show code how do you create and set up your custom window?

Comment: There is no need to. I've worked it out. I was missing the [.miniaturizable] style mask. Thank you

Comment: Anyway, I've noticed that I'm facing another problem. Now everything work and the view minimize, when I click on the icon in the dock the view de-minimizes correctly but I'm not able to drag the view around the screen. It seems as if the title bar disappears after this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

style mask [.miniaturizable] is required to call miniaturize(self) which will internally enable default Minimize button in the window.

```
@IBAction func miniApp(_ sender: Any) {
    self.window.styleMask.insert(.miniaturizable)
    self.window.miniaturize(self)
}
```

You can disable again the Minimize button again while the window appear to the user. Implement windowDidBecomeMain function and remove the minimize option

```
 func windowDidBecomeMain(_ notification: Notification) {
        
        mywin?.styleMask.remove(.miniaturizable)
    }
```